# Liquibase not picking up tablespace name in MySQL

Tags: mysql, liquibase, tablespace

I am trying to create a table in MySql using Liquibase. Below is the syntax I used, but Liquibase is not picking up the TABLESPACE at all.

```
<createTable tableName="TEST" tablespace="DATA01" >
    <column name="ID" type="java.sql.Types.BIGINT(19)">
       <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
</createTable>
```

But Liquibase is firing below command without TABLESPACE.

CREATE TABLE TEST (ID BIGINT(19) NOT NULL);

I am using Liquibase 3.5. What wrong I am doing?

Comment: is "DATA01" the same tablespace that you use in the connect string **--url="jdbc:mysql://hostname/tablespace**

Comment: we not using tablespace, but i have tested it and we have the same error

Comment: If I use native SQL the it works
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) TABLESPACE `DATA01`;
Only problem is Liquibase.